# How can i give offer for selected random products magetno

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, discount, sku

I need to give the offer for selected random products which is distinct categories. How can i give offers without using coupons code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options :

1) Catalog price rules

2) Shopping cart price rules with option NO coupon as below image :

[image]

for products, you can selected related skus in conditions.....